# Which approach is better when locking is required depending on state of several instance fields?

Tags: java, synchronization, locking

I have a class which has to initialize four instance variables pointing to four different templates. This initialization is done inside a method, which can be accessed by multiple threads at the same time. Synchronization is used to control how threads enter the initialization code block. The code goes as,

```
private void initializeTemplates(){
    if(template1 == null){
          synchronized(this){
             if(template1 ==  null)//initialize template
          }
    }
    if(template2 == null){
          synchronized(this){
             if(template1 ==  null)//initialize template
          }
    }
    //similar if blocks for the other two templates
}
```

This code seems ugly to me. I was wondering whether can I do this with using or operator, as,

```
private void initializeTemplates(){
    if(template1 == null || template2 == null || template3 ==null || template4 == null){
          synchronized(this){
             if(template1 ==  null)//initialize template
             if(template2 ==  null)//initialize template
             if(template3 ==  null)//initialize template
             if(template5 ==  null)//initialize template
          }
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with the second approach? Seems good to me.

Comment: The second approach will work just as well (or badly) as the first one.

Comment: Thanks, I also thought so but was just afraid I guess since this is production code. :)